# How to use Ajax file upload with other inputs?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

I am using php and codeigniter, I want to build a form with several inputs and file uploader. The file is uploaded before submitting the form or refeshing  it.
I tried [AJAX Multi File upload in CodeIgniter](http://carlofontanos.com/ajax-multi-file-upload-in-codeigniter/) but in order to upload the file the form must be submitted. I don't know how to use it with other inputs and  submitting the form after filling up all fields and uploading files

Comment: Can you post your code? This should be able to be done by passing a multi-part form to your ajax function with the file.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use formData in order to send files and other input both together.See below example for more reference

```
$("#add_product").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fdata = new FormData()

    fdata.append("product_name",$("product_name").val());

    if($("#file")[0].files.length>0)
       fdata.append("file",$("#file")[0].files[0])

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data:fdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false, 
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
    })
});
```